# Countable products of total measures

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $\kappa = \mathfrak{c} =2^{\aleph_0}$ is a real valued measurable cardinal with a witnessing measure $m:\mathcal{P}(\kappa) \to [0, 1]$ - So $m$ is a diffused (points have zero measure) $\kappa$-additive measure on $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$. Let $\mu = \otimes_{n < \omega} m$ be the countble product measure - So $\mu$ is defined on the sigma algebra generated by the family $\{\Pi_{n < \omega} X_n : (\forall n)(X_n \subseteq \kappa)\}$. Let $\mathcal{N}$ be the sigma ideal of $\mu$-null subsets of $\kappa^{\omega}$.

What can be say about the cardinal invariants associated with the ideal $\mathcal{N}$? For example, can either one of $add(\mathcal{N}), non(\mathcal{N}), cov(\mathcal{N})$ be $\aleph_1$?

Definitions: $non(\mathcal{N})$ is the least size of a set not in $\mathcal{N}$, $add(\mathcal{N})$ is the least size of a family $F \subseteq \mathcal{N}$ whose union is not in $\mathcal{N}$ and $cov(\mathcal{N})$ is the least size of a family of members of $\mathcal{N}$ whose union is $\kappa^{\omega}$.

Comment: For some background, what can be said about cardinal characteristics of a product of two total measures?

Comment: For finite products, all invariants equal $\kappa$ (by Fubini's theorem).

Answer (score 4):

- $non(\mathcal{N})=\kappa$.

  If $S \subseteq \kappa^\omega$ is of size $<\kappa$, then all projections $\pi_i(S)\subseteq \kappa$ are also of size $<\kappa$, hence have measure $0$.  But then $S\subseteq \prod_{i<\omega} \pi_i(S)$  also has measure $0$.
  (It seems to me that it would be enough that one of the projections is null.)
- $cov(\mathcal{N})$ is bounded by the covering number for the (Borel) null ideal on $2^\omega$, which I will call $\nu$. [EDITED.  I do not know if $cov(\mathcal{N})$ can be less than $2^{\aleph_0}$. The "standard" model for real valued measurable is obtained by adding $\kappa$ random reals to a model where $\kappa$ is measurable, so in that model we have $\nu=2^{\aleph_0}$, in which case my claim ``$cov(\mathcal{N})\le \nu$'' is irrelevant.]

  - Let $f:\kappa \to 2$ be such that $f^{-1}(\{i\})$ has measure $\frac12$ for $i=0,1$.
  - Define $F:\kappa^\omega\to 2^\omega$ by $F(x)(n) = f(x(n))$ for all $x\in \kappa^\omega$.
  - Then $F^{-1}(U) \subseteq \kappa^\omega$ has the same measure as $U$ for all open sets $U\subseteq 2^\omega$; hence $F^{-1}(N)$ is a null set whenever $N$ is.
  - Let $(N_j:j<\nu)$ be a family of null sets covering $2^\omega$.
  - Define $M_j = F^{-1}(N_j) \subseteq \kappa^\omega$.  Then $(M_j:j<\nu)$ is a cover of $\kappa^\omega$ by null sets.

Comment: I now think that  $cov(\mathcal N)=\nu=2^{\aleph_0}$ always holds if $\mathfrak c$ is rvm, but I don't have a proof yet.

Comment: You can do this by constructing an inverse measure preserving map $f: \kappa \to 2^{\omega}$ ($\kappa$ is any atomlessly rvm). This is also how we lift the measure on $\kappa$ to a total extension of Leb. measure.

Comment: If there is an isomorphism  between the given measure algebra (call it $(B_m,m)$)  on $\kappa$ and  the Lebesgue measure on $2^\omega$ (call it $(B_\lambda,\lambda)$, then of course the measure algebra $(B_\mu,\mu)$ will also be isomorphic. But I cannot show that $B_m$ has Maharam weight $\aleph_0$.  ($m$ might not be an extension of Lebesgue measure.)

Comment: If $\kappa$ is rvm and $m$ is a witnessing Maharam homogeneous measure on $\kappa$, then forcing with the associated measure algebra is same as adding $\theta$ random reals for some $\theta \geq \kappa^{+}$. In particular, the measure algebra of $m$ cannot be isomorphic to the standard Lebesgue measure algebra. This is a theorem of Gitik and Shelah.